# What is the DBMS_Crypto.encrypt() equivalent of DBMS_Obfuscation_Toolkit.DES3Encrypt()?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle19c, dbms-crypto

I am editing some Oracle code that includes DBMS_Obfuscation_Toolkit references. I read that [the DBMS_Obfuscation_Toolkit package is de-supported as of Oracle 10.2](https://oracle-base.com/articles/8i/data-encryption), and that I should upgrade my code to instead be use DMBS_Crypto.

I have this code...

```
dbms_obfuscation_toolkit.DES3Encrypt(
    input => UTL_I18N.STRING_TO_RAW(v_input,  'AL32UTF8'),
    key => UTL_I18N.STRING_TO_RAW(v_key,  'AL32UTF8'),
    encrypted_data => v_temp_raw
);
--039053190040155118183231113102022222017082162099111241054160152245207112101203096142122226097245
v_temp := UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_VARCHAR2(v_temp_raw);
```

...which expects length v_input to be evenly-divisible by 8, and yields a 96 character result ("039053...").

[The DBMS_Obfuscation_Toolkit documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/appdev.112/e16760/d_obtool.htm#i1003804) says that "Oracle's implementation of 3DES" defaults to the 2-key implementation, "in outer cipher-block-chaining (CBC) mode". But when I attempt to write a  `DBMS_Crypto.encrypt()` equivalent...

```
    --050127133161074179059208056044163133102098061207107114089045105193049199029095204025170130139068
    v_temp := UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_VARCHAR2(
            DBMS_Crypto.encrypt(
                src => UTL_I18N.STRING_TO_RAW(v_input,  'AL32UTF8'), -- Cleartext
                typ => DBMS_Crypto.ENCRYPT_3DES_2key + DBMS_Crypto.CHAIN_CBC + DBMS_Crypto.PAD_NONE,
                key => UTL_I18N.STRING_TO_RAW(v_key,  'AL32UTF8') -- Key
            )
        );
```

...I get back a different 96 character result ("050127...").

For the purposes of above, v_input ('Trees sway into 25MPH winds!    ') and v_key ('STACKOVERFLOW123456PSRV235KGNKNVEFHEF3404757543MNVOVCNALADNC6579') are the same.

To get the same result with `DBMS_Crypto.encrypt()`, what parameters should I be passing? **What is the DBMS_Crypto.encrypt() equivalent of DBMS_Obfuscation_Toolkit.DES3Encrypt()?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to supply a matching initialization vector (IV). If there was no original IV, then use `DBMS_CRYPTO.LEGACY_DEFAULT_IV = 0123456789ABCDEF`:

```
declare
  v_input    char(32) := 
    'Trees sway into 25MPH winds! ';
  v_temp_raw raw(32);
  v_key      varchar2(64) := 
    'STACKOVERFLOW123456PSRV235KGNKNVEFHEF3404757543MNVOVCNALADNC6579';
begin
  sys.dbms_obfuscation_toolkit.DES3Encrypt(
    input => UTL_I18N.STRING_TO_RAW ( v_input, 'AL32UTF8' ),
    key => UTL_I18N.STRING_TO_RAW ( v_key, 'AL32UTF8' ),
    encrypted_data => v_temp_raw
  );
  dbms_output.put_line ( v_temp_raw );
  
  v_temp_raw :=  sys.DBMS_Crypto.encrypt (
    src => UTL_I18N.STRING_TO_RAW ( v_input ,  'AL32UTF8' ), 
    typ => DBMS_Crypto.ENCRYPT_3DES_2key + DBMS_Crypto.CHAIN_CBC + DBMS_Crypto.PAD_NONE,
    key => UTL_I18N.STRING_TO_RAW ( v_key ,  'AL32UTF8' ),
    iv  => hextoraw ( '0123456789ABCDEF' )
  );
  dbms_output.put_line ( v_temp_raw );
end;
/

2735BE289B76B7E7716616DE1152A2636FF136A098F5CF7065CB608E7AE261F5
2735BE289B76B7E7716616DE1152A2636FF136A098F5CF7065CB608E7AE261F5
```

Comment: You are my hero. Where did you find that dbms_obfuscation_toolkit uses `hextoraw( '0123456789ABCDEF' )` as the default IV?! The documentation for both dbms_obfuscation_toolkit.DES3Encrypt() and DBMS_Crypto.encrypt () says the default IV value is `NULL`.

Comment: You're welcome. There's a couple of support notes that mention it. The `LEGACY_DEFAULT_IV` package constant was only added in 21c so there's reference to it in the [21c docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/arpls/DBMS_CRYPTO.html#GUID-44B594BB-3107-46E8-9878-3339D660574D)